# Why did Zhora hit Deckard?

Tags: blade-runner-series, blade-runner

Deckard weasels his way into Zhora's dressing room with a fiendish ruse, claiming to be an '*inspector for the American Federation of Variety Artists*'. She listens patiently to his babble for a short while, has a shower and then decides to elbow him in the stomach and murder him.

<sub><sup>Warning: NSFW - Nudity</sup></sub>

**What tipped her off that he needed killing?**

Comment: I remember coming across some people saying how it sounded like a blatant and weak lie to talk about a "Confidential Committee on Moral Abuses", which is what hinted her (since Nexus-6 are smarter). But, quite honestly, I don't see the problem in what he said. So... Yeah, that's a good question.

Comment: I agree with the unnamed people who say Deckard was not convincing. She’d certainly be on the lookout for blade runners.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - Which is fine, but why then (if his ruse was so transparent) did she put herself in such a vulnerable position before deciding to attack him?

Comment: I assume he didn’t retire her immediately because he was hoping to trick her into leading him to the other replicants. I’m not sure what vulnerable position you’re saying she put herself in. She didn’t confess to being a replicant. When she was in the shower, she wasn’t much more vulnerable to a gun than she was outside. And it gave her a way to make Deckard think he was fooling her so she could get close to him with the “zip me up” ruse.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - The script and the [deleted narration](https://youtu.be/kQGTVdLibuo?t=1589) both make it clear that he needs to be 100% certain. It's not until he sees the tattoo that he *knows*

Answer (score 1):

The film's [official novelisation](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/122327.Blade_Runner) indicates that she was tipped off by his apparent lack of interest in her (half-naked) body.

> He was through the door before she could stop him. That was the last
> time he was too fast for her.
>
> **She knew instantly that he was not looking at her the way other men
> did. Before he could stop her, she picked up a python from her act and
> swung it at him like a club.** He dove out of the way, whipping out his
> blaster as he hit the floor. But his shot went wild as her kicking
> foot doubled him over in pain. Then Zhora was out the door, running
> like the wind.
>
> <sub><sup>[Blade Runner: A Story of the Future](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/122327.Blade_Runner)</sup></sub>

Someone who's on the run from the law would be especially prone to overreacting to small clues like this.